# mongodb explain('executionStats') shows winningPlan as [Object]?

Tags: mongodb

when runnig any and mongoDB query `explain('executionStats')` I get the results as:

```
queryplanner: {    
    plannerVersion: 1,    
    namespace: 'db.Test',    
    indexFilterSet: false,    
    parsedQuery: { '$and': [Array] },   
    winningPlan: {      
        stage: 'PROJECTION_SIMPLE',      
        transformBy: [Object],      
        inputStage: [Object]    
    },    
    rejectedPlans: [ [Object] ]  
},...
```

why `winningPlan.transformBy` and `winningPlan.inputStage` are shown as `[Object]`. Is there a way to see the full output of it?

Comment: stringify the json `JSON.stringify(your json query)`

Comment: yes that would work in general, but running the same `explain()` query on another PC shows the results of `winningPlan.inputStage` 'expanded' (stringify already), so the question is if there is any option that controls this?

Comment: it depends on your playground, first PC's console/shell wraps bigger json in array and object to overcome messy look. its shell / console problem not mongodb or explain function problem.

Comment: both PC using the same mongoDB compass shell... that's the strange part

Comment: depends on shell version.